# Javascript object get code as string

Tags: javascript, object, tostring

First off, I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but every time I googled for 'object' and 'code' I got tutorial pages.

I want to know if there is any easy way to get the code associated with an object. Something like

```
function A(){
  this.name = 'Kaiser Sauze';
}
a = new A();
console.log(a.displayCode());
//OUTPUT
"function A(){ this.name = 'Kaiser Sauze';}"
```

I want to be able to view the code, modify it and reload the function, all from within the browser.  I wanted to know if there was some way to do this, or if I have to prime the pump by doing something like this:

```
function A(){
  this.name = 'Kaiser Sauze';
  this.code = "function A(){ this.name = 'Kaiser Sauze';}"
}
```

then every time the user loads up the text editor to view `this.code` I connect the onchange to update `this.code`.

EDIT

turns out yankee suggested a simple solution to this

```
function A(x){
  this.x = x ;
}
console.log(A.toString());
//OUTPUT
"function A(x){
  this.x = x ;
}"
```

but in my implementation the variable 'x' can be a function (actually a complicated object with variables, functions and sub objects which I mix in via a call to dojo.mixin), so what I really want is to know the code when instantiated, something like so

```
function A(x){
  this.x = x ;
}
var a = new A(function(){/*DO SOMETHING*/);
console.log(a.toString());
//OUTPUT
"var a = new A(function(){/*DO SOMETHING*/);"
```

but, as most of you already know, all that gets output is something like "Object". I have almost found a way around this, by putting the initialization in a function like so

```
function A(x){
  this.x = x ;
}
function _A(){
  var a = new A(function(){/*DO SOMETHING*/);
}
console.log(_A.toString());
//OUTPUT
"function _A(){
  var a = new A(function(){/*DO SOMETHING*/);
}"
```

but that is confusing, and then I have to go in and start parsing the string which I do not want to do.

EDIT: The reason I ask all of this is b/c I want to make code that is both dynamically executable and highly modular. I am dealing with the canvas. I want the user to be able to click on a, for example, rectangle, view its code, and modify and then load/execute it. I have a series of rules but basically I have a shape class and everything that defines that shape (color, transparency, fills, strokes...) has to get passed as a parameter to the object cosntructor, something like:

```
rect = new Shape({color : 'rgba(0,0,0,1)' , 
  x : 0 , 
  y : 0 , 
  w : 100 , 
  h : 100 ,
  draw : function() {ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
  }
});
```

This way the code is automatically modular, I don't have to worry about the color being defined at the top of the page, and then the height being defined half way down the page, and so on. Now the only thing I need is to somehow, pass as a parameter, the entire above string representation of the initialization. I could wrap it in a function and call toString on that, like so

```
function wrapper(){
  rect = new Shape({color : 'rgba(0,0,0,1)' , 
        x : 0 , 
        y : 0 , 
        w : 100 , 
        h : 100 ,
        draw : function() {ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
          ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
        },
        code : wrapper.toString()
      });
  }
```

but then there are two problems. 1) I have to manually remove the `function wrapper()` and trailing `}` as well as moving every line to the left by one tab. 2) there is no guarantee that a user will remember to include the wrapper function as it is totally unecessary for purposes of drawing. I am trying to think of a way where the wrapper would seem natural, but I can't think of any. But then again I haven't slept in over 30 hours.

Comment: +1 just for referencing Kaiser Sauze... although I think it is spelled Keyser Söze ;-)

Comment: @Jason: I can never remember how to spell it, so when I give out my number to the ladies, I go by Rolo Tomasi ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe no one suggested this (I apologize if this answer is somewhere in between the lines). I didn't think of it because at the time of development, all my work was clientside. All I really have to do is load the code once with Ajax as javascript. Once it is loaded and an object created, I load it again as a string and assign it to a variable in the object.

Answer (score 22):

OK... Reviewing again... I think that's what you want ;-).

```
>>> function A() {this.name ="foo";}
undefined
>>> A.toString()
"function A() {this.name ="foo";}"
```

Comment: Wow that is actually super cool. I usually slam Javascript for being totally inferior to Python, but in this case, it wins. Unfortunately it's not what I want. I realize now that it was a stupid question b/c objects don't have string representations. I will either reimplement everything as a class or find another way to do it. Thanks though.

Comment: also I could just put the object initialization inside a function and then call to string on that.

Comment: I guess I will edit the question to update everyone who is interested. Also, for some reason, when I do AT yankee it doesn't show up.

Comment: When replying to someone you are supposed to use the 'at' sign. Like user AT hotmail.com. But it did not work those last two times when I tried writing AT yankee

Answer (score 4):

Refer to code snippet below:

```js
function A() {
  this.name = 'Kaiser Sauze';
}

a = new A();

console.log(a.constructor.toString());

// output
// "function A(){
//   this.name = 'Kaiser Sauze';
// }"
```

When you do `new A()`, `function A` becomes the constructor of object `a`. Thus, you can reference `function A` via the `constructor` property of object `a`.

[Read more about Javascript constructor on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor).

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: added pretty-printing.

You could `JSON.stringify()` the argument of the constructor, if it is JSON-compatible. Here is a `toString()` function that builds on this idea, but with a slightly generalized version of `JSON.stringify()` that accepts stringifying functions:

```
function Shape(x){
    this.x = x;
}
Shape.prototype.toString = function() {
    function stringify(data, prefix) {
        function unicode_escape(c) {
            var s = c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
            while (s.length < 4) s = "0" + s;
            return "\\u" + s;
        }
        if (!prefix) prefix = "";
        switch (typeof data) {
            case "object":  // object, array or null
                if (data == null) return "null";
                var i, pieces = [], before, after;
                var indent = prefix + "    ";
                if (data instanceof Array) {
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        pieces.push(stringify(data[i], indent));
                    before = "[\n";
                    after = "]";
                }
                else {
                    for (i in data)
                        pieces.push(i + ": " + stringify(data[i], indent));
                    before = "{\n";
                    after = "}";
                }
                return before + indent
                       + pieces.join(",\n" + indent)
                       + "\n" + prefix + after;
            case "string":
                data = data.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\").replace(/"/g, '\\"')
                           .replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
                           .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
                           .replace(/[\x00-\x19]/g, unicode_escape);
                return '"' + data + '"';
            default:
                return String(data).replace(/\n/g, "\n" + prefix);
        }
    }
    return "new Shape(" + stringify(this.x) + ")";
};

var rect = new Shape({color : 'rgba(0,0,0,1)' , 
  x : 0 , 
  y : 0 , 
  w : 100 , 
  h : 100 ,
  draw : function() {ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
  }
});
console.log(rect.toString());
```

The output is:

```
new Shape({
    color: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 100,
    h: 100,
    draw: function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
})
```

Comment: wow I did not expect this many answers. Perhaps I should explain why I asked this question in the first place. I will edit again.

Comment: I edited my question again. I explain why I need it, and why I need not only the structure of the object, but the structure of the code itself. Therefore, I need, for aesthetic reasons, the tabs, spaces, and new line characters. Otherwise the user will type something, save it, and then when they reopen it, all of a sudden all of the code has been flattened to a single line only

Comment: There is no way you can recover the original spaces, tabs and newlines, unless the code is saved as a string in the first place (which may actually be the easiest path to follow). I edited my answer to improve the aesthetics of the output. However, this `toString()` is actually re-indenting with my indent style (four space indent, no space before ':'...), although the code was originally input using your style. You can obviously edit `toString()` to fit your style.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but if you call `toString()` on a function it will give you an exact copy of the implementation, including the spaces/tabs

Comment: I'm not sure this behavior is specified, it may be implementation-dependent. At least Firefox 3.6 and Qt 4.5 (QtScript) give a reformatted version of your function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that might work (using yankee's example). I am however unsure what happens if A already exists? Perhaps you should do a "delete(A);" before saving it in the storage.

```
// Create A
// function A() {this.name = "foo";}

var x = 'function A() {this.name = "foo";}'; // Store function to variable using A.toString();

// Save x in storage

// -- Page reload --

// Load and eval x from storage
eval(x);

var a = new A(); // Use A
alert(a.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function dumpObject(obj) 
{     
    var output = "";     
    for (var i in obj) 
    {         
        var msg = i + "= " + obj[i];         
        output += msg + "\n";     
    }     
    return output; 
} 

var myObject = {
    myName: 'Daniel',

    get_name: function()
    {
        return this.myName;
    }
}

alert( dumpObject(myObject) );
//this will output:
//
//    myName= Daniel
//    get_name=function()
//    {
//        return this.myName;
//    }
```

Here is my fiddle for that:
http://jsfiddle.net/DanielDZC/vXrQf/

Comment: I don't think that's what I am looking for, I want the code as it was, not just the properties.

Comment: That will display functions, properties etc. but each one of them seperately. you can adjust it so every loop is adding stuff to one string instead of alerting it. in fact let me change it...

Comment: Daniel, thank you for the jsfiddle. It definitely cleared things up :)

Comment: I see how it could work, but I want to preserve how the user writes the code (different spacing, tab size...) I will just use text areas and update the code and save a copy of the code within the code (pretty nifty if I may say so myself)

Comment: Hey Daniel, I just wanted to thank you for the code. I will go with your approach when getting object 'code' and I will go with psema4's approach (below) when getting class/other code. Essentially I will have three tabs, one for all code in a script, another for the class, and finally a third (non modifiable one) for the object. As the question I asked was about objects, and not classes, I will mark yours as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using on a production server, only for testing and debugging, but [there is a method named `toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource) which returns the source of a function as a String:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
console.log(add.toSource());
```

Outputs:

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

Available on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/dP453/1/

Note that Mozilla has marked this method as **non-standard** (which if you [read the details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource#Browser_compatibility) means "Only works in FireFox").

Comment: The link redirects to toString, and toSource doesn't seem to exist anymore. Firefox must have got replaced it with toString which isn't showing me the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for Reflection and/or Introspection support.  I'm not sure where the other major engines are at in this regards but SpiderMonkey's [Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) was recently referenced in an article on [Extension Introspection with Chrome Privileges](http://blog.mozilla.com/dherman/2011/06/28/the-js-parser-api-has-landed/).

Comment: I shied away from using parsers as I have little to no experience with them, but I might have to start. Another thing I was thinking was to store every function as a file then load them in index.html (or for efficiency merge them into a single .js file whenever one of the sub files is altered and only load that in index.html), then have each object generated by that file be aware of the file path. 

Comment: is there a reason my AT(@) signs are not showing up? I can no longer reply to specific users in the form of @ user (@user). Did the syntax change, or did I accidentally change my setting? For example I tried starting my previous comment with '@psema4' but I don't see it there

Comment: thanks for the link psema4. I will use this for the non object sections (ie. classes and entire scripts)