# Javascript to return the declared method as string

Tags: javascript

I am working with a svg element and I am trying to create a `text` element by dynamically retrieving a parameter that gets passed on to a function argument prior.

For example, a minimal sample

```js
const data = [{ "Month": 1, "Value": 10000, "MonthName": "Jan" }, { "Month": 2, "Value": 20000, "MonthName": "Feb" }];

const data2 = data.map((x)=>x.Value);

// targeting the svg itself
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

// variable for the namespace 
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

const text1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, "text")
text1.setAttribute('x', '10');
text1.setAttribute('y', '10');
text1.textContent = 'Value';
svg.appendChild(text1);
```

```html
<svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
</svg>
```

In this case, is there any way I can have `javascript` return the `const data2` statement as a string so that I can dynamically generate the text content like below

```js
const data = [{ "Month": 1, "Value": 10000, "MonthName": "Jan" }, { "Month": 2, "Value": 20000, "MonthName": "Feb" }];

const data2 = data.map((x)=>x.Value);

// targeting the svg itself
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

// variable for the namespace 
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

const text1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, "text")
text1.setAttribute('x', '10');
text1.setAttribute('y', '10');
text1.textContent = `data.map((x)=>x.Value)`.match(/(?<=x\.)[a-zA-Z]+/gm);
svg.appendChild(text1);
```

```html
<svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
</svg>
```

So instead of hardcoding,

```
text1.textContent = 'Value';
```

I desire to write the following as const data2 will vary. For example, it can be x.Month/x.MonthName

```
text1.textContent = {a function that returns const data2 expression as string}`data.map((x)=>x.Value)`.match(/(?<=x\.)[a-zA-Z]+/gm);
```

Comment: Hard time understanding your question, you could loop over the array and preform any desired actions with the current object?

Comment: To simplify if  I write `const x =[1,2].length`, is there any way in js I can have `[1,2].length` returned as a string? `x.toString();` returns `2` but I am desiring `x.someFunc` that returns `[1,2].length` instead of `2`.

Comment: Don't think thats possible. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583330/javascript-object-get-code-as-string) helps, but as you said does not give desired output.

Comment: How every, this sounds like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), care the explain 'why' you want to do this?

Comment: I already explained above with `svg` use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to get the expression that was used in the declaration of a a variable as a string.

You should solve this with a level of indirection. Put the property in a string variable, and use that when calculating `data2` and also for the `textContent`.

```
const data2_prop = 'Value';
const data2 = data.map((x) => x[data2_prop]);
...
text1.textContent = data2_prop;
```